# Is it possible to NOT map an assocation in ADO.NET entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm working on a project that uses ADO.NET entity framework as the ORM framework for getting data in and out the database. This all works great, but there's one association that I don't want to map. At least I don't want the developers to navigate from Product to OrderItem using the association between them.

Has anyone tried this scenario before I knows whether this will work and how I can model this into my domain-model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF 1 you can remove the relationship from the client schema in the EDMX and it will work fine, but I think it confuses the GUI designer. I believe this is fixed in the EF 4 designer.